# Best practices for storing references to AWS S3 objects in a database?

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-s3

We store files in Amazon AWS S3, and want to keep references to those files in a Document table in Postgres.  I am looking for best practices.  We use Python/Django, and currently store the URL that comes back from `boto3.s3.key.Key().generate_url(...)`.  But so many issues with that:

- Must parse the bucket and key out of the URL.
- Need to urldecode the key name.
- Doesn't support [object versioning](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectVersioning.html).
- Unicode support is easy to mess up, esp due to the urlencode/decode steps.

So, I'm considering storing the Bucket, Key, and Version in three separate fields, and creating the Key as a combination of the DB primary key plus a safely-encoded filename, but didn't know if there were better approaches?

Comment: Would love to hear how you ended up handling this or what you found for best practices. Consider answering your own question?

Comment: Basically, I do it like I said when "considering".

Answer (score 17):

Not sure if best-est approach, but we store:

- unique object ID (might be UUID) in database (for which Postgres has a native `UUID` type)
- bucket name and path in configuration (as we store all the objects of the same type under the same bucket+path)

That way you can at least:

- Move objects to a different bucket / path without havig to rewrite your whole database table
- Switch from S3 to local storage if you choose so
- Throw away your primary key (e.g. while partitioning tables) without loosing track of your objects